# How to drag and drop items of list throughout different component?

Tags: angular7, angular-components, dragdropmodule

In my project I have two **different** components .SideNav and Test. These components contain elements to be dragged. I need to drag the element from the SideNav component and drop it to the Test component and vice versa.
In material documentation they have demonstrated **DragDropModule** only for one component.